# PQGis Script Runner No Attribute Error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

i am new to pyqgis and using Script Runner to  test and see how it works. 
I have written  code in my script, My script is correct.I am getting the below error . How to get rid of it ?

```
      user_script.run_script(self.iface)

      ## Heading ##AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 
      'run_script'
```

Code in My script

```
     from PyQt4.QtCore import *
     from PyQt4.QtGui import *
     from qgis.core import *
     from qgis.gui import *


    def run_script(iface):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326', 'MyPoint' ,'memory')
    pr = layer.dataProvider()
    pt = QgsFeature()
    point1 = QgsPoint(20,20)
    pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
    pr.addFeatures([pt])
    layer.updateExtents()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```